# Should a GKEntity have properties or methods to access a component's features?

Tags: sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

I'm trying wrap my head around game entity systems and using GamePlayKit.
I'm struggling with the following scenario:

- `RenderComponent` is a `GKComponent` that references an `SKSpriteNode` to show my entity.
- `MetaDataComponent` is another component that holds various bits of information about an entity (like in my case, this would contain properties like `MapX`, `MapY`, ...)

I have a `CharacterEntity` that derives from `GKEntity`.

To initialise my entity, I pass the name of the texture to use for the sprite. This allows me to create the `RenderComponent`.

To initialise the `MetaDataComponent` I have three options and I wonder if one of them is considered best practice (and also, which one is worst practice)?

- For every property in my component, add a parameter to the `init()`
- Expose properties in the `Character` class which will update the properties of the component.
- Pass a model object to my entity and initialise the component from that.

My thoughts:

- Number 1: the more components my entity has, the more params I get...this is not really my preference.
- Number 2: an entity should be "stupid" and not carry any data. In it's purest form, an entity is just a number. Adding props in there "feels" wrong.
- Number 3: having a model object like `MetaData` to me feels best but also redundant because data is then in the component *and* in the model object. Maybe have the component store the model object instead of its properties?

To give another example: if I expect an entity to have a `RenderComponent`, I can query for that component and use it. Or I could add a method to the entity itself, like `setRenderPosition` which checks for existence of the required component and updates it. Again the question is, whether there's a right or wrong here in doing this?

Comment: Excellent question. This is the "forgotten" framework of Apple's gaming WIPs, much like CAKeyFrameAnimation is the forgotten means of animating on Apple platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for pure `Entity Component System` then the design consists of three parts:

`Entity`: Which is as you say, just a number. Nothing else.

`Component`: Which is just data. Nothing else.

`System`: The forgotten part. This is where the logic sits. You can inherit from `GKComponentSystem<GKComponent>` to create your own systems in SpriteKit.

This [article](https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/game-programming/understanding-component-entity-systems-r3013) and it's [supporting code](https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/game-programming/implementing-component-entity-systems-r3382) helped me a lot in understanding `ECS`. The [DemoBots example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html) is another one to look at for a spriteKit oriented implementation.

Since SpriteKit has it's own implementation of `ECS` and other quirks, some compromise is necessary I believe e.g. you need to render a node, so if you want a SpriteComponent, then you'll need to embed the node into the SpriteComponet or do something else - I preferred not to have a SpriteComponent, I created a VisualEntity that inherits from `GKEntity`, but that's my preference to focus on components that have behaviour that depends on the `update` run loop.

To answer your question about properties on entities, it doesn't seem necessary, since you can query the entity for any component you need access to.

```
guard let spriteComponent = entity?.component(ofType: SpriteComponent.self) else {
   return
}
```

The important thing is to be flexible, fit in with SpriteKit and be aware of the compromises you are making.

Comment: Looking at Apple's demos I see functions in the components and they use systems to update components in a specific order. To me this means, their approach is not the traditional or "pure" way. Would you agree? With your knowledge about ECS, would you mind having a look at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135259/how-to-add-the-concept-of-entities-and-components-into-an-isometric-tile-map too?

Answer (score 0):

An option to consider is having extensions on `GKEntity`.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

extension GKEntity {
    var isSelected: Bool {
        guard let component = self.component(ofType: SelectionComponent.self) else {
            return false
        }

        return component.selectionLocation != nil
    }
}
```

This makes the functionality available to all entities.

```
if self.someEntity.isSelected {
    // Handle 
}
```